# purpose of custom init in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, initialization

This may be TOO simple of a question, however, I cannot find any doc. on this at all.

I can find material on how to create a custom init, etc., but I can't find a simple explanation on why we would want to create a custom init for a class. Why is it necessary?

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    <#statements#>
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you are creating an NSString, don't you want to be able to specify the contents of the string?

Comment: There are ways to create an NSString object with the regular [alloc]init no? I'm trying to understand the difference between the two, and why it's necessary.

Comment: If you create an NSString with `[[NSString alloc] init]` then it is forever an empty string.  If you want stuff in it you must do `[[NSString alloc] initWithSomeStuff...]`.

Comment: Ok, so then doing the latter, initWithSomeStuff...., is a custom init technically? And additionally, the custom init method I put in my original question, is simply the same thing, except for a class, which would then automatically be spread across every instance made from that class, correct?

Comment: NSString is a class not much different from your class.  Look at the NSString docs and you will see a bunch of "custom" init methods.  Of course, you don't *have* to create such init routines, but they are a very good way to help assure that an object is consistently initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for the same reason one may want a constructor in C++.  It's to initialize your object. For example, if you're building a caching object, you may have an internal map that maps objects to a filename.  You would initialize that internal object in your init method so that other objects can call methods on your cache object right away.

If you have no special initialization to do, don't implement it.